# Parsing error: Rest element must be last element

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs gives "Parsing error: Rest element must be last element". Here is my code

```
    `const closePopup = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
    return (...prevState, selected: {})
    });
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

the return wasn't correct

```
const closePopup = () => {
  setState(prevState => {
    return {...prevState, selected: {}}
  });
}
```

or

```
const closePopup = () => {
  setState(prevState => ({...prevState, selected: {}}));
}
```